# GAE - ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

First of all, let me say that I did my homework and search for this error for several hours. I get this error when I try to access my Django 1.11 'Hello world' app deployed on GAE.

I'm perfectly able to run the app locally, inside a Docker with Python 2.7.

My current setup is as follows:

**Install**

```
virtualenv env
pip install -r requirements-vendor.txt -t lib/
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

**requirements-vendor.txt**

```
Django==1.11
```

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static/
- url: .*
  script: hi.wsgi.application

libraries:
- name: MySQLdb
  version: 1.2.5

skip_files:
- ^(.*/)?#.*#$
- ^(.*/)?.*~$
- ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]$
- ^(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*$
- ^(.*/)?\..*$
- ^env/.*$
```

**appengine_config.py**

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

#vendor.add('lib')  <--- tried that too
vendor.add(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'lib'))
```

The error is caused because the `lib` folder (which contains the Django framework and other libraries) isn't getting added to Python's PATH, but why? Why is GAE ignoring my `appengine_config.py`?